# Special character not showing up in select query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have an question about special characters not showing up in the query

```
DECLARE  @varName1 NVARCHAR(500); 
set  @varName1 = 'ÜCŞKUçÖ'
select '''' + @varName1 + ''' As Name1'
```

These are the Turkish characters. When I run the above query I get this character as `S` but it should come as `Ş`

In the database I have this column value as  `ÜCŞKUçÖ`

How can I solve the issue?

Comment: To define a string literal as Unicode (`nvarchar`), you need to prefix it with a **`N`** character! Try: `set  @varName1 = N'ÜCŞKUçÖ'`

Answer (score 3):

You're not actually storing it as a Unicode value...

```
SET @varname1 = N'ÜCŞKUçÖ';
SELECT @varname1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE  @varName1 NVARCHAR(500); 
set  @varName1 = N'ÜCŞKUçÖ'
select @varName1 As Name
```

For more in details http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180059.aspx

Comment: I need  something thing like this